# ListView inside another Listview shows Null check operator cannot be used on a null value error

Tags: flutter, dart, listview

I have a ListView inside of another ListView, both ListViews renders the value correctly if I put it separately, but when I put it inside of the itemBuilder of another LIstView I get the **Null check operator cannot be used on a null value error**. Not sure of what I am doing wrong here.

Here is my code -

```
List<String> contactsGroup = [
   'Contacts 1',
   'Contacts 2',
];

  Widget _showModalBottomSheet(contactsGroup, totalContacts) =>
      DraggableScrollableSheet(
        initialChildSize: 0.7,
        maxChildSize: 0.9,
        builder: (_, controller) => Container(
          decoration: BoxDecoration(
              color: Colors.white,
              borderRadius: BorderRadius.vertical(top: Radius.circular(10))),
          padding: EdgeInsets.all(10),
          child: ListView.separated(
            itemBuilder: (context, x) => Padding(
              padding: EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
              child: Align(
                alignment: Alignment.centerLeft,
                child: Column(
                  children: [
                    Text(contactsGroup[x]),
                    ListView.builder(
                      itemBuilder: (context, y) => Padding(
                        padding: EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
                        child: Align(
                          alignment: Alignment.centerLeft,
                          child: Column(
                            children: [
                              Text(contactsList[y].displayName),
                            ],
                          ),
                        ),
                      ),
                      itemCount: contactsList.length,
                    ),
                  ],
                ),
              ),
            ),
            separatorBuilder: (context, index) => Divider(
              color: Colors.black,
            ),
            itemCount: contactsGroup.length,
          ),
        ),
      );
```

Here is how the call to the above method is made -

```
              onTap: () async {
                await contactsBottomSheet.fetchContacts();
                contactsList = (contactsBottomSheet.phoneContactsOnBol +
                    contactsBottomSheet.phoneContactsNotOnBol);
                int totalContacts = contactsList.length;
                List<String> contactsGroup = [
                  'Contacts on Bol',
                  'Contacts not on Bol'
                ];
                //contactsList.sort((a, b) => ["displayName"].compareTo(b["displayName"]));
                showModalBottomSheet(
                  isScrollControlled: true,
                  isDismissible: true,
                  backgroundColor: Colors.transparent,
                  context: context,
                  builder: (context) => _showModalBottomSheet(
                      contactsGroup, totalContacts),
                );
              },
```

And this is the error I get on the terminal[image]

Comment: I think it isn't coming from this code snippet. Can you add more and pinpoint the errors or add the terminal errors?

Comment: @YeasinSheikh I get the error only when I add the inside ListView. I have added more code as requested.

Comment: I have added a link to the file as well to the original post

Comment: Your method is async so the data will not be ready immediately and it will take sometime. widgets DO NOT wait for the data (there are some exceptions though) to come and will be rendered immediately. so before rendering list view you should check if data is ready. in your case what I can think of is before loading padding you should check if y is null or not.

Comment: Do you want inner list also scrollable?

Comment: No I dont want the inner list to be scrollable.

Comment: @Benyamin If you look at the OnTap() method on the above code, I am awaiting the function call before proceeding with the call to the _showModalBottomSheet method. So only if the contactsList list is loaded the call is made to the _showModalBottomSheet widget.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem was nested ListView, while inner taking infinite size, if you wrapped that with `SizedBox(height: x)` that will solve the issue. But according to the conversation, you don't want that scrollable, so I'm adding them on column and removing inner Listview.

**Demo Widget** I have used dummy data for test purpose, hope you will get it.

```
  Widget _showModalBottomSheet(int contactsGroup, int totalContacts) =>
      DraggableScrollableSheet(
        initialChildSize: 0.7,
        maxChildSize: 0.9,
        builder: (_, controller) => Container(
          decoration: BoxDecoration(
              color: Colors.white,
              borderRadius: BorderRadius.vertical(top: Radius.circular(10))),
          padding: EdgeInsets.all(10),
          child: ListView.separated(
            itemBuilder: (context, x) => Padding(
              padding: EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
              child: Align(
                  alignment: Alignment.centerLeft,
                  child: Column(
                    children: [
                      Text("Contact"),
                      ...List.generate(
                        4,
                        (index) => Padding(
                          padding: EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
                          child: Align(
                            alignment: Alignment.centerLeft,
                            child: Column(
                              children: [
                                Text("data here"),
                              ],
                            ),
                          ),
                        ),
                      )
                    ],
                  )),
            ),
            separatorBuilder: (context, index) => Divider(
              color: Colors.black,
            ),
            itemCount: contactsGroup,
          ),
        ),
      );
```

Let me know if it solves your issue.

Comment: Thanks @Yeasin. I was not able to implement it the exact same way, but your code helped a lot.